# JavaFX line chart change color shape

Tags: java, javafx

I have this window:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1960, 2020, 10);
    xAxis.setLabel("Years");

    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 350, 50);
    yAxis.setLabel("No.of schools");

    LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    lineChart.setTitle("Chart");

    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series.setName("No of schools in an year");
    Platform.runLater(() -> 
        series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-line").setStyle("-fx-stroke: black;")
    );

    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1970, 15));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1980, 30));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1990, 60));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2000, 120));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2013, 240));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2014, 300));

    lineChart.getData().add(series);

    var scene = new Scene(lineChart);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

I want to change the color of series, but what I can achieve is to change color of line, but shape not.

How I can change the color of shape?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762804/how-can-i-change-the-points-colors-of-a-scatterchart-using-javafx-inside-java-co/52763051#52763051

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using `CSS`. The key here is looking up all the nodes associated with a series and changing the color of the nodes. The first series is `.series0`.

> Key Code:

```
Set<Node> nodes = lineChart.lookupAll(".series" + 0);
for (Node n : nodes) {
    n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, white;\n"
            + "    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;\n"
            + "    -fx-background-radius: 5px;\n"
            + "    -fx-padding: 5px;");
}
```

> Full Code

```
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScatterChartSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1960, 2020, 10);
        xAxis.setLabel("Years");

        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 350, 50);
        yAxis.setLabel("No.of schools");

        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Chart");

        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series.setName("No of schools in an year");
        Platform.runLater(()
                -> {

            Set<Node> nodes = lineChart.lookupAll(".series" + 0);
            for (Node n : nodes) {
                n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, white;\n"
                        + "    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;\n"
                        + "    -fx-background-radius: 5px;\n"
                        + "    -fx-padding: 5px;");
            }

            series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-line").setStyle("-fx-stroke: black;");
        });

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1970, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1980, 30));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1990, 60));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2000, 120));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2013, 240));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2014, 300));

        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        var scene = new Scene(lineChart);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> Update: Try this!

```
for (Data<Number, Number> entry : series.getData()) {      
    entry.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, white;\n"
        + "    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;\n"
        + "    -fx-background-radius: 5px;\n"
        + "    -fx-padding: 5px;");
}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to set color dynamic via setStyle. There is a way to set via series?

Comment: I added an update @KunLun. I think the update answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

What about some css? These are list of css that can be used with line chart.You can combine `lookup`, `setStyle` and css property to change the style dynamically.

```
.chart {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-background-image: url("icon.png");   
}
.chart-content {
    -fx-padding: 30px;    
}

.chart-title {
  -fx-text-fill: #4682b4;
  -fx-font-size: 1.6em;
}

.axis-label {
  -fx-text-fill: #4682b4;
}

.chart-legend {
   -fx-background-color:  transparent;
   -fx-padding: 20px;
}

.chart-legend-item-symbol{
   -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.chart-legend-item{
    -fx-text-fill: #191970;
}

.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: #e2ecfe;
}
.chart-vertical-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: #3278fa;
}
.chart-horizontal-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: #3278fa;
}
.chart-alternative-row-fill {
    -fx-fill: #99bcfd;
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
    -fx-stroke-width: 0;
}
```

More on https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm

Comment: I want to use setStyle to set color dynamic.